# Ho wto get start and end Georgian date of Hijri Year My Query attached

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2012, hijri

i am trying to get start and end date of hijri year but getting difficult to find any solution my query is,

```
SELECT datepart(year,try_convert(date,'19/07/1440',103)) from Items
```

result i am getting is `1440`

How to find the `georgian calender` `start date` and `end date` of year `1440`

Hopes for your suggestion

Comment: The style code for Hijri is `130` and `131`: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `Hijri` date by format `131`

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(DATE, '14400101', 131) [Start Date]
, DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(DATE, '14410101', 131)) [End Date]
```

Result:

```
Start Date End Date
---------- ----------
2018-09-11 2019-08-30
```